# Issues with griddata

Tags: matlab

I am using griddata to interpolate some values. However, I could find some issues with it. It is showing me warning of x-y duplicate values. However, when I checked the data to see if all the x-y pairs are unique,I found that they are.

Then why is it showing this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are they are close to being replicates, and griddata apparently uses a tolerance for that. One solution is to use [consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354-consolidator) to average the points, supplying a tolerance.